# Products by category are not displayed on the frontend (Magento 2.4.0)

Tags: category-products

After having made a stormy migration from magento 1.8.1.0 to Magento 2.4.0 in the backend I can see all the categories and their products, however in the frontend when selecting any of the categories in the menu the products are not show, it is as if the category is empty. Please help

Comment: Try to save one product from backend and also do re-indexing then clear cache

Comment: @Nilesh Nor can I add new products or edit existing ones. I was leaning into thinking about some issue with product attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost going crazy looking for a solution finally thanks to the help of several people in this forum how I found how to do it:

1.- Elasticsearch was not installed on my server, I had to ask the provider to do it (take into account the correct version of Elasticsearch depending on your version of Magento 2.X).

2.- And this if it was the final solution, if not for this forum I would never have found it, here I leave them: (sorry I lost the link, but I had copied the answer :))

There are still some sorting problems when using an elastic search as a catalog search engine. To solve it, you can apply the following patch specifically to Magento 2.3.2 and Elasticsearch 6+.

Go to the file below and add a plugin in the class below.
Vendor \ Magento \ module-elasticsearch \ Model \ ResourceModel \ Fulltext \ Collection \ SearchResultApplier.php

Find the apply () method and replace it with the following function. This is a hotfix introduced by Magento recently by adding $ this-> collection-> setPageSize (null); to the SearchResultApplier.php class

```
public function apply()
{
    if (empty($this->searchResult->getItems())) {
        $this->collection->getSelect()->where('NULL');
        return;
    }
    $ids = [];
    foreach ($this->searchResult->getItems() as $item) {
        $ids[] = (int)$item->getId();
    }
    $this->collection->setPageSize(null);
    $this->collection->getSelect()->where('e.entity_id IN (?)', $ids);
    $orderList = join(',', $ids);
    $this->collection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
    $this->collection->getSelect()->order("FIELD(e.entity_id,$orderList)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Josue,**

Do check the Product **Url rewrite**, sometimes this issue occur after migration, or you can also check the **Cron scheduling**, is this on schedule or not, it take sometime after migration to stable, and also please do run the **Re-indexing** for all and then check

It will help you out, these are the **highlighted** point according to your issue!

Thanks

**Munesh**.

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I am quite new developing in Magento 2. I would appreciate if you could tell me a little more about what I should check in the rewrite Url to be able to solve the issue, the same with the CRON, I have already reindexed several times after making small data in the DB. Thank you very much, I am aware of your comments.

Comment: Nor can I add new products or edit existing ones. I was leaning into thinking about some issue with product attributes.

Comment: ok thats great, please do accept the answer, if it was helpfull for you in anyway! as it will helpfull for others also, Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

From the 2.4 version of Magento you need to use elastic search. Please navigate: admin => config => catalog => catalog search and choose elastic search 7
Click 'Test connection' to see if it appears success or not. If it does, reindex.
If it doesn't, restart Elastic search and config to the right port and retry.

Hope that help!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It seems that elasticsearch is not working. How can I restart it on my remote server? After the migration I had a problem to edit the categories, it was something related to the eav_attribute_set table and now I can't edit or create new products either. Please I need your help

Answer (score 0):

If all the other solutions didn't work, try to change the value for "Use Flat Catalog Category" and "Use Flat Catalog Product".

Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront

After that do a reindex and cache flush.